# N Stage string compression : Algorithm for decompression

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

You have a key-value pair given:

"Adsddf" : ?

"ds?xsc" : :

"csdcs:" : #

...n items.

The goal is to decompress a string :
Example : String: "ac3d:cs?" will translate to : ac3ddsAdsddfxsccsAdsddf

Basically in place substitution for every character.

What is the best algorithm to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best is somewhat nebulous, but here is a possible solution.

Pseudo code

```
# reverse lookup
rev = {}
for key, value in items
  rev[value] =  key

result = ""

decode(input)
  for letter in input
    if letter in rev
      decode(rev[letter])
    else
      result.append(letter)
```

Just be careful that there are no cycles ...

Comment: Missing an `else` there, but yeah. This is the cleanest approach, and that’s a good default assumption for ‘best’ (particularly since any sane algorithm will have the same time complexity).

Comment: @Sneftel oh yes, I missed that.